# HTTP 500 Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have moved Laravel to hosting in root directory: `public_html`

In this directory I made `.htaccess` file with content:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

It means that web site will be showed from directory `public`.

When I try open web site via URL I get error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

What is happen and how to fix?

Comment: Check your logs. You can find detail debug report there. Show what errors you are getting there.

Comment: Where I can find Laravel logs?

Comment: storage/logs/larave.log. Don't copy everything, just share the last one.

Comment: It is empty, which any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if I'm right, but check your `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php` just remove the file if present and you will get the stack trace of your error

Comment: No, I get 500 by Chrome, not from this file

Comment: ohh.. then I think problem is with your server configuration and not with laravel

Comment: can you try using the default .htaccess file that comes with laravel

Comment: Colud you share this file please? I have two file, one in root, and second in public directory

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/public

Comment: check .htaccesss file in above link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121436/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-dev).

Comment: I believe you need to change something in your index.php or kernel.php, I had this same problem once. Laravel is still looking for the folder `public`

Comment: you must change the bootloader paths on index.php

Comment: As nothing is generated in Log, you should check storage folder permission too. Make sure the storage folder and bootstrap folder has writable permission.

Comment: Are you using anything like cpanel?

Comment: -Problem was solved, the topic my be close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your folder permission once try giving it a permission of 777